# How to find all rows that have same values but possibly permuted rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

Cannot figure our how to count all rows that have same values in any order. E.g in this example

```
1| Jay   | Jo
2| Jay   | Jo
3| Jay   | Jo
4| Jo    | Jay
5| Linda | Luke
6| Linda | Luke
7| Luke  | Linda
8| Luke  | Wendy
```

I am looking for the following output:

```
Jay   | Jo    | 4
Linda | Luke  | 3
Luke  | Wendy | 1
```

I was killing myself over it for 2 days. Everything does not work. 
Joins lead to overcount, unions don't work as well. since they preserve entries with both orders ... I understand that I probably need to do some sort of self join and to consider two copies of the same table. But what manipulations to perform, I don't know!
Really confused! Please help!

If possible I would appreciate answer in SQL Lite but probably any syntax would work. I just need to understand the logic how to compose the tables.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way in SQLite would be to use `least` and `greatest`.

```
select least(col1,col2),greatest(col1,col2),count(*)
from tbl
group by least(col1,col2),greatest(col1,col2)
```

Comment: apologies..sqlite has no `least` and `greatest`.

Answer (score 3):

Just a little logic switch should do the trick

**Example**

```
Select Col1
      ,Col2
      ,count(*) as Hits
 From (
        Select case when col1<Col2 then Col1 else Col2 end as Col1
              ,case when col1<Col2 then Col2 else Col1 end as Col2
          from YourTable
      ) A
 Group By Col1,Col2
```

**Returns**

```
Col1    Col2    Hits
Jay     Jo      4
Linda   Luke    3
Luke    Wendy   1
```

Comment: what syntax is that? I need to translate it to SQL Lite so I need to know what language it is written on.  Is it possible to do without creation of a new table?

Comment: I did not really work with advanced statements before and I just assumed there is some intersection/union/join trick to be done so I though it does not really matter coz syntaxes for these cases are very similar